# dotTrace: Who's calling my method?

Tags: c#, .net, jetbrains-ide, dottrace

I'm using dotTrace to profile a compiler that's having some performance issues.  Being a compiler, the call stack is heavily recursive, and folding in call tree view just tends to make things even more confusing more often than not.

When I sort the Plain List view by Own Time, I find that a certain method is using a large amount of the run time.  Looking at the code, there isn't much I can do to make that method faster, but I believe that adding some memoization could make it so it doesn't need to be called nearly as often.  The problem is, I'm having a heck of a time figuring out where to add it.

When you click on a method in the top pane in Plain List view, it shows methods that this method calls in the bottom pane, which is kind of useful, but as near as I can tell it doesn't give you the far more useful information of *what methods are calling this method*.  Is there any way to get statistical information on that, so I know where to focus on adding memoization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the plain list view of the `All Calls` tab just right click on your method and select `Open Current Method Instance` (or select the method and press `CTRL+T`). This opens a new tab for your method in dotTrace.

In this new tab click on the `Backtrace` view on the left side to see all calls to that method.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  It shows that 96% of calls are coming from one specific place, so now I know where to focus on...

Comment: After adding memoization, it decreased the runtime of the entire compile cycle by over 50%, so thanks again!